# Why does my servlet request.getParameter return null?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm having a problem with the request. It always returns "null", but I don't know why. I want it to return a name.

This is my servlet:

```
public class MinServlet extends HttpServlet {


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>Syvtabellen - fra en servlet</title></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<p>Her er syv-tabellen:<br>");

    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        out.println("Syv gange "+ i +" er: "+ 7*i +".<br>");
    } 
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    String parameterværdi = request.getParameter("navn");
    out.print( "Værdien af parameteren 'navn' er: <br>" + parameterværdi );
}

}
```

This is the index.xml:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
</body>
```

This is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MinServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>konti.MinServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MinServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MinServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Do I've to add it in the index.xml somehow? I know that the parameter returns null if the parameter doesn't exist, but I don't know how to fix it :)

Comment: It's a request parameter, so you need to submit a form (or add the parameter `?navn=something` to the URL).

Comment: What URL? I can't see it :)

Comment: It's running on localhost

Comment: Err, the URL that is invoking the Servlet.

Comment: `<url-pattern>/MinServlet</url-pattern>` ?

Comment: No. Somewhere there is a client. The code you have written expects the client to provide a `navn` parameter to your Servlet. That parameter goes into the URL that the *client* uses to invoke the Servlet. You don't seem to understand your own code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are following a tutorial. As Elliott said in his comment you need to have a parameter called "navn" in you view to catch it from your servelet otherwise you will get a null. Or else there should be a query string called "navn".  Here I can't see any parameter called "navn" in your client side.

For example: http://www.java4s.com/java-servlet-tutorials/example-of-request-getparameter-retrieve-parameters-from-html-form/

According to your code: 
index.html

```
<font face="verdana" size="2px">
       <form action="getVal" method="post">
           First way to pass request Param <input type="text" name="navn"><br>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
</font>
```

TestApp.java

```
public class TestApp extends HttpServlet  
{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");

        String n1=req.getParameter("navn");
        pw.println("Requested  Value" +n1);
        pw.close();

    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>

    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>sumOfTwoNumbers</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>java4s.OngetParameter</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>TestApp</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/getVal</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Or else you can pass query string as following

Second way to pass Request param:
index.html 
[Click here](/getVal?navn=%27myName%27)

Comment: Yes, I'm following a tutorial, and in the tutorial they also say that I've to add the parameter ?navn=something to the URL, which I don't understand :)

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin Your answer would be a lot more use if it actually answered the question, i.e. demonstrated the use of a parameter called `navn`, rather than something completely different.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the suggestion. But I added an example to help him to understand the use of request.getParameter(). So he can find out the error by himself without giving the answer straight way . :)

Comment: @Nasc I cannot see any form in your index file. Do you have any other views? where is this "/MinServlet" url pattern calling from?

Comment: Well despite the best efforts of three people it is apparent that the OP is still baffled.

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin No I don't

Comment: @Nasc Above example shows  two possible ways to pass the request parameter to backend.

Comment: @Nasc So, for about the third time, who is invoking this servlet?

Comment: It's supposed be a Web page with a URL

Comment: Exactly, so the parameter has to be part of that URL, either via the mechanism shown here or directly appending it to the URL.